# What is the equivalent of location.replace() for Angular

Tags: angular, routes

What is the equivalent of location.replace() for Angular
to change the path without linkbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use navigate :)

```
   constructor(private router: Router,private service: HeroService){}
   replace(hero: Hero) {
        this.router.navigate(['/hero', hero.id]);
   }
```

Comment: from where import the router?

Comment: import { Router } from '@angular/router';